# mongoexport with read preference containing tags

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongoexport

I'm trying to export a collection from my MongoDB but I would like the export to be from a specific secondary server using tags in read preference. 
My MongoDB consists of one replica set: primary-secondary-secondary.
One secondary is tagged as *"tgg":"tgg1"* and the second one is tagged as *"tgg":"tgg2"*.

This replica set is configured to be a single shard. With mongos client running on port localhost:47010.

I'm using mongoexport 3.4

The mongoexport command I'm running:

`mongoexport --port 47010 --db test --collection test_collection --out ~/tmp/mongo/test.json --readPreference '{"mode":"secondary", "tags":[{"tgg":"tgg2"}]}' --verbose`

I'm getting the following error:

***Failed: Failed to call say, no good nodes in replset1***

But, if I don't specify the tags but only that the mode is "secondary" everything is working.

Am I missing something here?

### EDIT

So I found what was wrong, I had to go to their source code in github for that but still. I must say that the error messaging is not sufficient.
It seems I supplied a list of tags and not just a Json object.
So the following command worked:

`mongoexport --port 47010 --db test --collection test_collection --out ~/tmp/mongo/test.json --readPreference '{mode:"secondary", tags:{"tgg":"tgg2"}}' --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the desired secondary with `--host` parameter in the `mongoexport` command itself:

```
mongoexport --port 47010 --db test --collection test_collection --out ~/tmp/mongo/test.json --host <ip-or-hostname-of-secondary-tagged as tgg2>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work but eventually I'll have several shards and I'll need to work through mongos in order to get the sharded collection.